# Converting output into .csv file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I am new to Python, and I am currently writing code to parse through an excel sheet of websites, look at websites that have been modified more than three months ago, and then pull out the names and emails of contacts at those sites. My problem now is that whenever I run the code in my terminal, it only shows me some of the output, so I'd like to export it to a .csv file or really anything that lets me see all the values but I'm not sure how.

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("filename.csv")
data.sort_values("Last change", inplace = True)
filter1 = data["Last change"]<44285
data.where(filter1, inplace = True)
print(data)
```

note: the 44285 came from me converting the dates in excel to integers so I didn't have to in Python, lazy I know but I'm learning

Comment: data.to_csv('newfile.csv')  https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html

Answer (score 1):

You can try converting it to a csv.

```
data.to_csv('data.csv')
```

Alternately if you want to just view more records, for example 50, you could do this:

```
print(data.head(50))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can share your parser code also, I think we can save your from the hassle of editing the excel in between the process. Or maybe something from here with a few more lines.

To solve your problem use

```
data.to_csv("resultfile.csv")
```

or if you want an excel file

```
data.to_excel("resultfile.xlsx")
```

Comment: Thank you that worked for the csv export, but to be perfectly honest that is all the code I have, most of it I got online and from other people, and looking at it something is definitely off, my thought process was just to parse through with pandas and pick out the ones with date value less than the one I put above, do you have any recommendations on where I can find more info or do you have any thoughts?

Comment: Let's assume your date column is named "Date"
#################NEWLINE
enddate = input("Please input the deadline :")  
#################NEWLINE
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%d.%m.%Y')
#################NEWLINE
dfs = df[(df['Date'] <= enddate)]